# How to recursively create a python dictionary from unknown depth & width but also add values?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, recursion, list-comprehension

This is a follow up question to this post:
[How to recursively create a nested dictionary of unknown size in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66220108/how-to-recursively-create-a-nested-dictionary-of-unknown-size-in-python)

I need to somehow incorporate a value for each element as well.

Starting with the previous solution:

```
def unpack(obj):
     return {str(o): unpack(o) for o in obj.get_items()}
```

Every item also has a value associated with it besides the name.
I tried the following, but it wouldn't work:

```
def unpack(obj):
     return {{str(o): unpack(o), 'value':o.value} for o in obj.get_items()}
```

I get a "unhashable type: 'dict'" error.
The resulting dictionary should look something like the following:

```
example_dict = {'level_1': {'level_2':{},'value':'b'},'value' : 'a'}
```

Where each nested level would have a value associated with the name of the level.

Comment: Dictionaries are not hashable, meaning you can't use `str(o)` as the key if `o` is of dict type. What is the datatype of `o`? That determines if it would work or not.

Comment: 'o' or 'obj' is an instance of a class. It has a variety of methods that allows me to access various types of data. I'm using the CLR library to use some .NET libraries & functions.

When you use str(o) it simply returns a unique string identifying a particular level in the hierarchy.

If I remove the 'value':o.value portion, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so if I understood you correctly you want to put an object tree into a hierarchical dictionary. My first go at this would be

```
import random

names = ['foo_%s'%i for i in range(10)]

# Make hierarchical test case
class Test:
    def __init__(self, depth):
        self.name = random.choice(names)
        if depth > 1:
            self.child = Test(depth-1)
        else:
            self.child = None
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
        
test = Test(3)

# The meat
def unpack(x):
    ret = dict()
    for k, v in x.__dict__.items():
        try:
            ret[k] = unpack(v)
        except AttributeError:
            ret[k] = v
        
    return ret
    
print(unpack(test))
```

‚unpack‘ tries to recursively find all variables of an object and writes them into a dict. If that fails it returns the variable. Note that ‚x.**str**‘ has to be implemented.